# Flask HTTP/1.1" 302

Tags: python, flask

I'm sorry to bother, since this problem has been already asked, but I tried everything that I found in the internet and I'm still not able to find the issue :'(

So basically, I did a flask app for controlling leds on my raspberry Pi and then I tried to implement a login system for it. Connecting to my account was not an issue, but when I try to access the interface for controlling the Leds I get ""GET /led_control/ HTTP/1.1" 302" and then redirected back again to login. The interface should only be accessed when I'm logged in.

This is the code for logging in:

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'username' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap

#Login form
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
@app.route("/login/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if not (username and password):
            flash("Username or Password cannot be empty.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            username = username.strip()
            password = password.strip()

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user and check_password_hash(user.password_hashed, password):
            session[username] = True
            return redirect(url_for("user", username=username))
        else:
            flash("Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")

#User Home form
@app.route("/user/<username>/")
def user(username):
    if not session.get(username):
        abort(401)
        
    return render_template("user.html", username=username)
```

When I click on the interface Button I get logged out

```
<h2> {{username.title()}} - Click here to access the interface!</h2>
  <a href="{{ url_for('led_control')}}" role="button">Interface</a>
```

and this is the code for controlling the LEDs

```
@app.route("/led_control/")
@login_required
def led_control():

    for p in pins:
        pins[p]["state"] = GPIO.input(p)

    template = { "pins" : pins}
    return render_template("led_control.html", **template)

@app.route("/<activate>/<action>") # request url with pin number
def action(activate, action):
    change = int(activate) # convert pin from url into int
    device = pins[change]["name"]

    if action ==  "on":
        GPIO.output(change, GPIO.HIGH)
        text = device + "is on"

    if action == "off":
        GPIO.output(change, GPIO.LOW)
        text = device + "is off"

    for p in pins:
        pins[p]["state"] = GPIO.input(p)

    template = {"pins" : pins}

    return render_template("led_control.html", **template)
```

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: Can you extract *just* the part of your code for the routes that you call, the "login system" and the GET /led_control route? The route definition, how it processes the request, and what it gives as a response. You can omit the parts for controlling the LEDs or calling other external functions because those shouldn't be relevant. If you have any Flask after_request and before_request functions or route decorators, post those as well. It seems you got logged-out so you are redirected to login. Basically I am hoping you can post a [mcve].

Comment: Links to codes in Github are discouraged, because the code can change at any time or disappear altogether, rendering this post only useful for you and useless to future/other readers or potential answerers. An [mcve] is really needed.

Comment: ohh sorry, you are right ^^ I hope the part of the code I posted will be helpful

Comment: Have you tried adding some print statements in the `login_required` decorator to understand why it is redirecting? Print `session` and check for key `username` and if it’s not there check `session` in your login code after `username` should have been set as a key.

Comment: @barny thank you for the hint, I did resolve my problem :D